# Issue Returning Entity Framework 4.0 Entity from a WCF REST Service

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, rest, .net-4.0

I'm trying to return an EF object from a WCF REST service.

It works fine when I do not eagerly load any child objects but once I do, I get a 404 error when I try browsing the service using Internet Explorer 7.0.

Comment: Please show the code. Please put a try/catch around the operation and post ex.ToString() if there's an exception.

Comment: Hi, do you want an answer to this question? Then please post the code and display ex.ToString() like I asked above.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks.

I discovered that the exception was casued by the serializer 'chocking' on the cyclic references between the parent and child entities. I fixed it by making the child entity a protected rather than a public property on the parent entity.

I'd be glad to hear of better ways to deal with the situation.

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to the amount of data being sent back.

The server breaks the connection when the amount of data goes over the configured limit.

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200803155348/http://geekswithblogs.net/vitus/archive/2009/07/12/wcf-rest-services-hosting-in-the-iis7.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

try `[DataContract(IsReference=true)]`